# Does the phrase "I am ascending" in John 20:17 mean it is an act in progress?

Tags: greek, john

Does the phrase "I am ascending" in John 20:17 mean it is an act in progress that could be completed before Jesus appears to those Jewish disciples who were hiding behind locked doors later that night in John 20?

Answer (score 1):

The verb here is Ἀναβαίνω (Anabainō) which is Present Indicative Active - 1st Person Singular.  Thus, "I am ascending" is an accurate translation.

Jesus said this while standing in front of Mary with the instruction to tell the disciples, early Sunday morning.  By the time she departed and travelled the short distance and reported to the disciples, Jesus certainly would be on His way, that is "ascending" to the Father.  Thus, it is an accurate report of His actions.

Between the time that Jesus said this to Mary and when He appeared to the frightened disciples late that same day, He had ascended to the Father and returned to speak with them.

Ellicott comments:

> The present is used of the future, which He regards as immediately at
>   hand. The message to the brethren is an assurance that the going to
>   the Father, of which He had so often spoken to them, was about to be
>   realised. The victory over death has been accomplished. This
>   appearance on earth is an earnest of the return to heaven. "Unto My
>   Father," He now says, "and your Father." It is a more emphatic
>   expression than "our Father" would have been. "I ascend unto My
>   Father. Because He is My Father, He is also your Father, and you are
>   My brethren. My victory over death was the victory of man, whose
>   nature has in Me conquered death. My ascension into heaven will be the
>   ascension of human nature, which in Me goes to the Father."

Answer (score 0):

New International Version
John 20:

> 17
> Jesus said, “Do not hold on to me, for I **have not yet ascended** to the Father. Go instead to my brothers and tell them, ‘I **am ascending** to my Father and your Father, to my God and your God.’”

‘I am ascending
Ἀναβαίνω (Anabainō)
Verb - Present Indicative Active - 1st Person Singular

The Greek present tense indicates continued action, something that happens continually or repeatedly, or something that is **in the process of happening**.

Jesus was telling Mary that he had an important appointment with the Father in real-time.

Jesus had risen, Matthew 12:

> 40
> For as Jonah was three days and three nights in the belly of a huge fish, so the Son of Man will be three days and three nights in the **heart** of the earth.

Jesus had just ascended from the heart of the earth to the surface of the earth and was in the process of ascending higher. He didn't want Mary delaying this process of the first ascension after the crucifixion.